# Paypal button not working in hotmail emails

Tags: email, button, paypal, paypal-ipn, hotmail

I'm having an issue with the paypal button code below not working when sent to a Hotmail address.  It shows in the email source code and in the email message just fine.  But when you click on it, it directs you to the paypal homepage.

This works fine in gmail and yahoo mail emails, but not Hotmail.  The code below is what is used and how it appears in the emails.

Is there a reason why it's doing this, I can't find anything on it.

```
<form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="NGQ2YWY1Nz000mZiYmEty1I2ZTMzZTcwOxxzMmI4Y="/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Acme Company [testes]"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="4"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://site.com/paypal.php?payment_status=ipn"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://site.com/paypal.php?payment_status=cancel"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://site.com/paypal.php?payment_status=success"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="0"/>
  <input type="image" src="http://site.com/images/paypal_logo.png" width="197" height="48" class="paypal_button" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal!" title="Make payments with PayPal!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use a `<form>` in emails -- never, ever. It cannot be trusted to work.

What is generating this `<form>` with POST variables for you, and why is it not using an `<a>` link with GET variables instead?

Comment: Then what would be an equivalent in a link?

Comment: I asked what was generating this form to go from there...

But well, you can generate a link by going to PayPal.com and creating a button, unchecking Save Button at PayPal under Step 2, creating the button, and switching to the "Email" tab to view it as a link.  You should then be able to adapt that link to your needs with the variables and URL-encoded values you want.

Comment: To answer your first part of the question, it's not a plugin, it's a function that includes this form in the email.  I will see what Paypal does with the link and then try to add my variables to that then.